# how to achieve where condition in lowdb Json?

Tags: java, json, npm, nosql

below is my lowdb json, I need to get mrp of productid 1222, how to achieve this in lowdb?

```
{
 "product": [
{
  "productid": "1221",
  "productname": "Lemon",
  "mrp": "10",
  "rate": "20"
},
{
  "productid": "1222",
  "productname": "Coconut",
  "mrp": "20",
  "rate": "30"
},
{
  "productid": "1223",
  "productname": "Big Onion",
  "mrp": "30",
  "rate": "40"
}
 ]
}
```

Note: As of now I'm Iterating `product` array and used if condition to fetch `product 1222`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the match criteria to the `find`.
For eg:

```
db.get('product').
find({"productid": "1222"})
.value()
```

will return

```
{ productid: '1222',productname: 'Coconut', mrp: '20',  rate: '30' }
```

You could do `db.get('product').find({"productid": "1222"}).value().mrp` if you need to extract the value of mrp.

Here is a working sample, for completeness sake:

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter = new FileSync('./products.json')
const db = low(adapter)

console.log(db.get('product').find({"productid": "1222"}).value())
```

Comment: awesome man. Thanks! I will update and accept this as answer once i reach my criteria.